# PyTest: How to add X-BULK-OPERATION with HTTP_AUTHORIZATION for session credentials (headers)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, pytest, pytest-django

I'm writing test for Django Rest Framework with PyTest. There was a problem with headers X-BULK-OPERATION because I can't add X-BULK-OPERATION with HTTP_AUTHORIZATION on header.

my code

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def session(django_db_setup, django_db_blocker):
    with django_db_blocker.unblock():
        user = User.objects.get(email=TEST_EMAIL)
        user.set_password(TEST_EMAIL)
        user.save(update_fields=["password"])
        client = APIClient()
        url = reverse("login_sys:login")
        response = client.post(url, {
            "email": TEST_EMAIL,
            "password": TEST_EMAIL
        })
        client.credentials(**{"X-CSRFToken": response.cookies['csrftoken'].value})
        yield client
        client.logout()
```

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def choose_crm(session):
    crm = Crm.objects.get()
    url = reverse("crm:set-jwt", kwargs={"pk": crm.id})
    response = session.get(url)
    session.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=response.data.get("token", None), 
                        **{"X-BULK-OPERATION": True})
    yield session
    session.logout()
```

error 
`{'detail': "Header 'X-BULK-OPERATION' should be provided for bulk operation."}`

Debug:print request, as you can see I have Bulk-Operation in header but still gives the error no BULK-OPERATION in header 
`'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION': 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJjcm1fdXNlciI6MSwiY3JtX2lkIjoxLCJncm91cF9pZCI6MSwiZGVhbF9wZXJtIjp7ImNyZWF0ZSI6MSwiZGlzcGxheSI6MSwiZWRpdCI6MSwiZGVsZXRlIjoxLCJleHBvcnQiOjF9LCJjb250YWN0X3Blcm0iOnsiY3JlYXRlIjoxLCJkaXNwbGF5IjoxLCJlZGl0IjoxLCJkZWxldGUiOjEsImV4cG9ydCI6MX0sImxlYWRfcGVybSI6eyJjcmVhdGUiOjEsImRpc3BsYXkiOjEsImVkaXQiOjEsImRlbGV0ZSI6MSwiZXhwb3J0IjoxfSwidGFza19wZXJtIjp7ImNyZWF0ZSI6MSwiZGlzcGxheSI6MSwiZWRpdCI6MSwiZGVsZXRlIjoxLCJleHBvcnQiOjF9fQ.Wrd89a8jpRnNu1XhNsOKFAkNQR6v_Y_X0nKySocMtLM', 'HTTP_X-BULK-OPERATION': True}`

Comment: Why have you prefixed the header with "HTTP_"? You don't need to, this is just something that Django does when adding request headers to `request.META`

Comment: changed ```**{"HTTP_X-BULK-OPERATION": True}``` to ```**{"X-BULK-OPERATION": True}``` still error in bulk operation

Comment: Can you post more of your test code? What is `session`?

Comment: edited question

Comment: I would try passing the header with underscores `HTTP_X_BULK_OPERATION` but other than that I don't know